# Giving formik reference to custom hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, formik

I'm trying to separate formik validation to a custom hook. The hook returns yup falidation schema, but it needs functions from formik bag to build that schema. **How could I get the reference to formik in the component root, and pass it down to custom hook?** The component looks like this:

```
export const MyView = () => {
    let formikRef: FormikProps<FormData> | undefined = undefined;
    const { validationSchema } = useValidationSchema(formikRef);
    ...
    return (
        <Formik
            initialValues={initialValues}
            onSubmit={submitForm}
            enableReinitialize={true}
            validateOnChange={false}
            validateOnBlur={false}
            validationSchema={validationSchema}
        >
            {(formik) => {
                formikRef = formik;
                return (
                    <>
                        ...
                    </>
                );
            }}
        </Formik>
    );
}
```

This method of getting the ref does not work. The ref actually receives the correct value, but the custom hook only receives initial value (undefined). I also tried storing the ref to state, but that leads to infinite render loop. Additionally I tried using innerRef, but again, custom hook always receives undefined reference.

EDIT:
Managed to get it working by using useFormik and FormikProvider. Now there's a problem with reference order: formik uses validationSchema and other way around. I solved this by adding a function to custom hook:

```
const { validationSchema, setFormik } = useValidationSchema();

const formik = useFormik<FormData>({
    initialValues: initialValues,
    onSubmit: submitForm,
    enableReinitialize: true,
    validateOnChange: false,
    validateOnBlur: false,
    validationSchema: validationSchema,
});
setFormik(formik);
```

Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: The easiest and cleanest approach for me would be to transform the <Formik /> component by useFormik hook, and then send the formikbag to the validation hook

Comment: With that approach, will I be able to use <Field />?

Comment: Nope but you can use : [getFieldProps](https://formik.org/docs/tutorial#getfieldprops) instead

Comment: hey @wekso can you explain me more about the use case of extracting the validation to a hook? or share (if possible) the code of the hook `useValidationSchema`?
In my understanding the validation schemas are tight to the model of the form, and can not be reused that much (I may be very wrong). Thanks!

Comment: Validation schema is not reused. Validation in my case includes quite complex rules. E.g. some config is loaded from redux store, and certain fields may be required depending on config. The reason for separating validation logic is to make the top level component of the view more simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up with

```
export const MyView = () => {
    const { validationSchema, setFormikForValidation } = useValidationSchema();

    const formik = useFormik<FormData>({
        initialValues: initialValues,
        onSubmit: submitForm,
        enableReinitialize: true,
        validateOnChange: false,
        validateOnBlur: false,
        validationSchema: validationSchema,
    });

    setFormikForValidation(formik);

    return (
        <FormikProvider formik={formik}>
            ...
        </FormikProvider>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can you `useFormikContext` hook. This is a hook provided by `formik` and you can use it in any of the children of a `formik` instance.

Your form:

```js
import Formik from 'formik';

const Form = (props) => {
  return (
    <Formik {...props}>
      <FormBody/>
    </Formik>
  );
}
```

your form body:

```js
import {useFormikContext} from 'formik';

const FormBody = () => {
  const {values, ...etc} = useFormikContext();

  return (
    ...
  );
}
```

Comment: I think this is the correct answer. There's no need to create your own hooks when using Formik, they already provide everything you need.

Comment: @Thremulant There may be a need to create a hook to do something other than passing formik data but in that case too you can use this hook inside that hook.

Comment: that's my point. You can use the `Formik hooks` to get all the data of the form inside your `FormBody` component. 
What I don't understand is why would @wekso want to create a hook for the validation only. I should just ask him :)